# Background image not showing in jsp dynamic web project

Tags: html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee

Hi I am trying to use a background image in home.jsp page.when i run the project image is not loading a red cross mark is showing instead of the image

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
       <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ac-styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body  >
<img src="img/bg.png">


<p> Hello This Is The Home Page For your J2ee Spring Application</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I had placed the image under

[image]

when i run the application the result is

[image]

please help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: mere a path problem. Need to know your directory structure.

Comment: Maybe you need some `.`'s because the image folder is a few layers above the home.jsp. Try `../img/bg.png`

Comment: @DejaVu You wud be needing those '../' two times.

Comment: hi @pramod.nikam.dev i had placed image in WebContent/img/bg.png and jsp file in WebContent/WEB-INF/views/Home.jsp

Answer (score 1):

The JSP file is not in the same folder as of image file root folder is present. So either you have to move your .jsp file in web-content folder or you should use backspace commands like:

```
<img src="../../img/bg.png">
```

This should work.
Conversely the best method would be to migrate your image file in web-inf/views folder.That would be easy but not recommended for big projects.

> note that I included "`../`" two times. In your directory structure it
>   is needed. For more information read the refering manual for HTML
>   src's.

Comment: thank you for your help,but its not working.. i had tried the other way copying image to views folder then also the result is same.

Comment: if you are copying the ONLY image to view folder than in src you should write only name of the image with extension(png in your case.)For your folder structure above code is working in my system.